# Cannot find my app.module.ts file while working in a NX workspace

Tags: angular, nx-workspace

I am using NX workspace to work with two applications, a front-end and a back-end. The front-end seems to be working fine, but I cannot see the app.module.ts file for my dashboard (back-end). The application is running smoothly. Can someone help?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fine. Angular v15 bootstraps your application in standalone mode (`"standalone": true`). This can be seen by examining your `main.ts`.

Components maintain their own context (rather than being inferred from an ngmodule context) via the `imports` array on the actual component. If your component uses another you simply import it also.

Comment: Thank you. So if I need to have an app.module.ts file, how can I import it to an existing project? Since the tutorial I am following has one, I feel it would be easier to just go that way.

Comment: If you link to the tutorial I'll provide the up-to-date version of it

Comment: Thank you, it is a course on skillshare, I doubt you can access it if you don't have an account.

Comment: Ok, recommend contacting the course creator to let them know. If you use your Nx Console > generate > @nrwl/angular:application > Show More, I would expect there to be the option to put --standalone=false